# How much is 2 + 2?

Tags: php, random, form, quiz

I'm currently working on a kind of PHP Quiz about mathematical calculations.  We show a mathematical equation, and user need to input his answer.

Currently, this is what I have written:

```
echo '<div class="table-title">Super Quizz</div>';

echo '<div class="row text-center quizz">';

function addition($x, $y) { return $x + $y; }
function substraction($x, $y) { return $x - $y; }
function multiplication($x, $y) { return $x * $y; }
function division($x, $y) { return $x / $y; }

do {
    $firstNumber = rand(1, 10);
    $secondNumber = rand(1, 10);

    $operatorsCharacteres = array('+', '-', 'x', '/');
    $operatorsLetter = array('addition', 'substraction', 'multiplication',             'division');
    $operande = array_rand($operatorsLetter);
    $result = call_user_func_array($operatorsLetter[$operande],     array($firstNumber, $secondNumber));
}while($result < 0);


echo $firstNumber.' '.$operatorsCharacteres[$operande].' '.$secondNumber.' = <input type="text" name="answer" maxlength="3" class="input-quizz" >';
echo '<input type="hidden" value="'.$result.'">';

echo ' </div>';

echo '<div class="table-title"><a href="#" type="submit">I valid !</a></div>';
echo 'Result : '.$result;
```

If something is wrong, or not optimised, please, tell me, and teach me.

Comment: @Vogel612 : Thank you for edit it, but it seems you deleted my second question, about the best way to save user data. Is it voluntary ?

Comment: Yes that is planned. Unfortunately chnaging what your code does is not in scope for codereview, which is why I removed the request for additional 'features' from your question. If you have further questions feel free to ask away in [chat]. You can find me in the 2nd monitor ;)

Comment: Hi @Jerem.Bartman., nice of you to accept my answer! In the meantime, I noticed chumkiu's answer, and it's much better than mine, so I suggest to accept that one instead!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Naming

The naming of the arrays related to the operators is not so great:

- In `$operatorsLetter` you have the names of functions that do some operation. `$operatorFunctionNames` or even `$operatorFunctions` would be a better name.
- In `$operatorsCharacteres` you have the symbols of operations. These are normally not called characters. So `$operatorSymbols` would be a better name.
- In `$operande` you have the key of a random operator. That's not an operand. In the operation `3 + 9`, the operands are 3 and 9, but in your code it's "addition". So `$operatorIndex` would be a better name.

With these renames, the code is slightly easier to understand:

```
$operatorSymbols = array('+', '-', 'x', '/');
$operatorFunctions = array('addition', 'substraction', 'multiplication', 'division');
$operatorIndex = array_rand($operatorFunctions);
$operatorSymbol = $operatorSymbols[$operatorIndex];
$operatorFunction = $operatorFunctions[$operatorIndex];
$result = call_user_func_array($operatorFunction, array($firstNumber, $secondNumber));
```

I also introduced the helper variables `$operatorSymbol` and `$operatorFunction`,
to shorten the lines later in the code that use them.

#### Printing in PHP

An easier way to print in PHP is to simply move text outside of `<?php ... ?>` blocks.
For example these lines at the beginning of your script are a bit tedious to write using `echo` statements:

> ```
> echo '<div class="table-title">Super Quizz</div>';
>
> echo '<div class="row text-center quizz">';
> ```

Instead, you could change your script to put the beginning `<?php` after those lines, like this:

```
<div class="table-title">Super Quizz</div>
<div class="row text-center quizz">

<?php
function addition($x, $y) { return $x + $y; }
function substraction($x, $y) { return $x - $y; }
// ...
```

I would do similarly near the end of the file too, like this:

```
// ...
echo $firstNumber.' '.$operatorSymbol.' '.$secondNumber;
?>
 = <input type="text" name="answer" maxlength="3" class="input-quizz" >
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $result ?>">

</div>

<div class="table-title"><a href="#" type="submit">I valid !</a></div>
Result : <?php echo $result ?>
```

Comment: Don't use `echo $firstNumber.' '.$operatorSymbol.' '.$secondNumber;`, use `echo $firstNumber,' ',$operatorSymbol,' ',$secondNumber;`. This has a small performance gain. Since strings are immutable in PHP, a new string containing the contatenation of all those strings is created. And then `echo`ed. With commas, you are sending multiple strings, which are sent directly to the default output mechanism. No more processing needed. No concatenation. It is a small performance optimization, but it's kinda worth it. It helps a lot in the future.

Answer (score 10):

I would:

- improve (avoid) the PHP & HTML mixing.
- use one associative array instead of two array in order to define the operators
- avoid a `while`. If the problem is the substraction, then check if the result is < 0 and switch the variable. Because in your case the substraction case will be **less probable** than other operators.
- call_user_func_array could be simply replaced [legitimately](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php) by a variable (`$funcName()`)

#### code

```
<?php
function addition($x, $y) { return $x + $y; }
function substraction($x, $y) { return $x - $y; }
function multiplication($x, $y) { return $x * $y; }
function division($x, $y) { return $x / $y; }

$firstNumber  = mt_rand(1, 10);
$secondNumber = mt_rand(1, 10);

$operators = array(
    'addition'       =>'+', 
    'substraction'   =>'-', 
    'multiplication' =>'x', 
    'division'       =>'/'
);

$operator = array_rand($operators);

$result = $operator($firstNumber, $secondNumber);

if($result < 0) {
    list($firstNumber,$secondNumber) = array($secondNumber, $firstNumber);
    $result *= -1;
}

?>
<div class="table-title">Super Quizz</div>
<div class="row text-center quizz">
    <?=$firstNumber?> <?=$operators[$operator]?> <?=$secondNumber?> = <input type="text" name="answer" maxlength="3" class="input-quizz" >
    <input type="hidden" value="<?=$result?>">
</div>
<div class="table-title"><a href="#" type="submit">I valid !</a></div>
Result : <?=$result?>
```

Just a note about `<?=`. This syntax could be disabled by .ini configuration if your PHP is <=5.3. In this case you must use the most verbose `<?php echo`

Another thing about `rand`. I've replaced automatically in my mind `rand` with `mt_rand` because this last "Generate a **better** random value". It's not so important in this context but it's a good thing start to use it for all.

Comment: Avoid using `<?=$result?>`. This can be disabled on his server/php installation. Use a proper `<?php echo $result;?>` for portability.

Comment: Well, your comment is correct. However we talk about versions not yet supported (5.3 has supported until Aug 2014 and since 5.4 `<?=` is always available). So I prefer to leave it as answer, but insert a note for "vintage" installations

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I don't understand some points. First, you write `<?=`  but is it a correct way, if later, i want to add more calcul to the operation ?

Comment: It isn't a 'vintage installation' thing. It's a simple setting you can disable since PHP4. It comes disable **by default** with XAMPP, which has PHP5.5.

Comment: Since PHP 5.4.0, `<?=` is always available. http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php

Comment: I'm not saying it isn't available. I'm saying that it can be disabled **AND** comes disabled **by default** on XAMPP. You should add this note.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel the point is that it can NOT be disabled since 5.4.

Comment: @Jerem.Bartman. `<?=` it's a shorthand of verbose `<?php echo`. It's a correct way to print something if you don't worry compatibility with old versions (because old versions must have `short_open_tag` `ON` in `php.ini` conf). For other operations, what you means?

Comment: @chumkiu Actually, i didn't use shorthands dur to lack of portability. There may be conflicts with ASP tags. (and to follow all your opinions. Others opinions, i mean actual it's `number operator number` but maybe later I will add more number & operator, like `3+6/4*9+8`

Comment: @Jerem.Bartman. `<?=` has no conflicts with anything, in any configuration, in any server IF you are under PHP5.4+ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use (see ending note). If you are under <= 5.3 then yes, it's better to you to use `<?php echo`. For other things: I can only review the code that you've posted. If you want to add more options, then it's better for you to post another question with your code approach :-)

Comment: @chumkiu Okay, thank you for your answer and your patience